# Adjacency list определение root node в mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Все привет!

Имеется такая таблица

```
 _________________
 | ID | PARENT_ID|
 +----+----------+
 |111 |   444    |
 |222 |   111    |
 |333 |   222    |
 |555 |   666    |
 +----+----------+
```

Из таблицы видно, что имеется 2 root node - 444 и 666.
В таблице отсутствуют `id` у которых `parent` равен `NULL`, или `0`, или сам себе и т.д.
В таблице более 100000 записей.

**ВОПРОС:**

Как наиболее оптимально определить все root node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.parent_id
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t2.id = t1.parent_id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

или там

```
SELECT t1.parent_id
FROM table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM table t2 
                  WHERE t2.id = t1.parent_id
                 )
```

или ещё как...

Что эффективнее на ВАШИХ структуре и наполнении - предсказать не берусь.